# Retrieving full command line (w/ pipes &c) from a running bash script

Tags: bash

How can I get the complete line of code running in the bash in a script that is run from within this line?

```
ping -c 2 google.com & ping -c 2 aol.com | grep aol & sh myscript.sh
```

where I want to retrieve the complete upper line in myscript.sh somehow.
My current approach is:

```
 ping -c 2 google.com & ping -c 2 aol.com | grep aol & ps -ef --sort=start_time
```

And then correlate the PPID and the start time of the process to get what was run.

```
UID  PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
nm+  2881  6599  0 12:09 pts/1    00:00:00 ping -c 2 google.com
nm+  2882  6599  0 12:09 pts/1    00:00:00 ping -c 2 aol.com
nm+  2883  6599  0 12:09 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto abc
nm+  2884  6599  0 12:09 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -ef --sort=start_time
```

I dont like it since I am unable to say how the processes are connected (pipes or just parallel execution) and therefore its impossible to reconstruct the exact line that was run in the bash. Also it feels to hackish for the right way.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve. And what needs to run in parallel. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve. What is your expected/wanted output

Comment: I want myscript.sh to ouput the line it is run within, e.g. ping -c 2 google.com & ping -c 2 aol.com | grep aol & sh myscript.sh

Comment: You want myscript .sh to get the *actual* line as it was input (typed, possibly) on the command line? Including all the pipes, and including itself?

Comment: You can't do this. (Imagine your program wasn't called from bash, what then?) [What problem are you actually trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @Gilles I am writing a little script that takes the output of some inhouse scripts, formats it and pastes it into a DB. Since the tasks are depending on which command is acctually providing the data I thought it would be easiest to get the complete line. Since its not possible I will provide the command to run as an argument (myscript.sh command -abc) and eventually break argument autocompletion.

Comment: @Evert: Yes exactly. Somebody types in the line into a bash and I want to get the complete line. Support for other shells would be nice but is no must have.

Comment: Is the target platform known? I'm relying on some Linuxisms in my current answer; can adjust them to a different platform, but still need to have a specific platform to target.

Comment: Actually -- would having the source file and line number under execution be good enough? That's actually somewhat easier. :)

Comment: Actually -- part of the issue here is that `foo & bar & baz` **isn't** one command; it's three commands on the same line: `&` is a command separator just as `;` is (but with the side effect of putting the former command in the background). Retrieving via the line of source is thus your only reasonable option if you want such separate-commands-on-the-same-line-of-code conflated.

Comment: Target is Linux with bash on it. I am actually ok with the answer "there is no good way to do it" - Just wanted to know if I missed something obvious.

Comment: @ciko, would generating a log stream giving source filename and line number suffice for your purpose? *That* would be easy to generate, and one could then look up the actual line of source from the data at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can grep "pipe" from `lsof` and find the correlated commands from the pipe id for a process and find the process id and look for details for the correlated processes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bash 4.0 or newer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec 3>"$1"; shift
BASH_XTRACEFD=3 PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:+'
set -x
source "$@"
```

...if saved as `bash_trace`, used as:

```
bash_trace logfile scriptname arg1 arg2 ...
```

...then, to look up the actual line number, one can use something like the following:

```
IFS=: read -r filename lineno _ < <(tail -n 1 logfile)
sed -e "${lineno}q;d" <"$filename"
```